# Laravel homestead access denied for user "root"@"localhost"

Tags: php, laravel

*Edit*
Laravel using homestead throw error like this after trying to run `php artisan migrate` while in vagrant ssh.

Some of the solution saying that i should change the port from 3306 to 33060. But even change it in env.file and config/database.php gave the same outcome.

I use phpmyadmin to see the database. Almost tried all the solution that i can find but still do not fix this problem.

Comment: but what's the error? is it always the same? can you provide it?

Comment: Yes, it is always access denied. I find the solution, it turns out for laravel/homestead you MUST use username 'homestead', database 'homestead' and password 'secret'. It never occurs to me this would be the problem since the tutorial and (solution online)  change username, database, password. The tutorial i followed use valet.

Answer (score 0):

try to change :

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;`

to :

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

in your phpmyadmin config file

Comment: have you confirmed that the password is correct? if so then try using the command ```php artisan config:cache```

Comment: I think my password is correct because it find during php artisan migrate. Also fine (testing rest api) if not using homestead. But since guzzlehttp cause problem in hosting, i had to use homestead. Also already tried that command.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, it turns out for laravel/homestead you MUST use username 'homestead', database 'homestead' and password 'secret'. It never occurs to me this would be the problem since the tutorial and (solution online) change username, database, password. The tutorial i followed use valet.